# React - unable to get the store state to pass in a child class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm dispatching an action to recreate the `userForEdit` state variable in UserEditDialog FunctionComponent, for it to be available through useSelector in my component. Becauase I want to pass it to the child class component `UserEditForm`.

Here is the code of UserEditDialog

```
import {useAppDispatch} from "./../../../../../../redux/store";

interface UserEditDialogProps{
  id: string;
  show: boolean;
  onHide: () => void;
}
export const UserEditDialog : React.FunctionComponent<UserEditDialogProps> = ({
  id,
  show,
  onHide,
}) => {
  // Users UI Context
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
// Where useAppDispatch is exported from store.ts as with "@reduxjs/toolkit";
// export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
// export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>(); 
  useEffect(() => {
    // server call for getting User by id
      dispatch<any>(actions.fetchUser(id));  //should we add .then callback?
  }, [id, dispatch]);

  // Users Redux state
  const { actionsLoading, userForEdit } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => ({
      actionsLoading: state.users.actionsLoading,
      userForEdit: state.users.userForEdit,
    }),
    shallowEqual
  );
  // server request for saving user
  const saveUser = async (user: User) => {
    if (!id) {
      // server request for creating user
      await dispatch<any>(actions.createUser(user));//.then(() => onHide());
      onHide();
    } else {
      // server request for updating user
      await dispatch<any>(actions.updateUser(user));//.then(() => onHide());
      onHide();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      size="lg"
      show={show}
      onHide={onHide}
      aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
    >
      <UserEditDialogHeader _title="Edit User" />
      <UserEditForm
        saveUser={saveUser}
        actionsLoading={actionsLoading}
        user={userForEdit}
        onHide={onHide}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

And here is UserEditForm component

```
 interface UserEditFormProps{
    saveUser:any,//(fileName:Blob) => Promise<void>, // callback taking a string and then dispatching a store actions
    user:User,
    actionsLoading:boolean,
    onHide:() => void,
  }
  interface UserEditFormState{
    name: string,
    cardNo: string,
    faceFileInput:React.RefObject<any>,
    groups:any,
    groupName: string
  }
  export class UserEditForm extends React.Component<UserEditFormProps,UserEditFormState> {
  //  state: UserImportFormState;
    constructor(props:UserEditFormProps){
      super(props);
      //this.loadUsers=props.loadUsers;
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.state={
        name: props.user.name,  //undefined user on props
        cardNo:props.user.cardNo, //undefined user on props
        faceFileInput: React.createRef(),
        // this should be a dropdown if there are groups or hide if no groups are there
        groups:[{id:"abc",name:"ABC"},{id:"def",name:"DEF"},{id:"fgh",name:"FHG"}],
        groupName: props.user.groupName, //undefined user on props
      }
    }

    //React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    handleInputChange(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const name = event.target.name;  
//      event.target.type
      const value = event.target.value;
      this.setState((current) => ({ ...current, [name]: value }))
    }

    handleSubmit(event:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const name:string=this.state.name;
      const cardNo:string=this.state.cardNo;
      const face:File=this.state.faceFileInput.current.files[0];
      const groupName:string=this.state.groupName;
      //construct updated user before submit
      //if 
//      const user:User= {name,cardNo,face,groupName}
      // this.props.saveUser(props.user.id,name,cardNo,face,groupName);
    }
  
  render(){
  return(
....
)}}
```

And the fetchUser Action

```
export const fetchUser = (id:string) => (dispatch:Dispatch) => {
  if (!id) {
    return dispatch(actions.userFetched({ userForEdit: undefined }));
  }

  dispatch(actions.startCall({ callType: callTypes.action }));
  return requestFromServer
    .getUserById(id)
    .then(response => {
      const user = response.data;
      dispatch(actions.userFetched({ userForEdit: user }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      error.clientMessage = "Can't find user";
      dispatch(actions.catchError({ error, callType: callTypes.action }));
    });
};
```

When I debug the code the problem is `dispatch<any>(actions.fetchUser(id));` in UserEditDialog component is not being dispatched before the child component UserEditForm is composed. The reason might be, useEffect is async. But how to dispatch the action and get the latest store state before composing child component. Is there anything wrong with using the class component as child of a FunctionComponent?
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by just adding a case to handle when userForEdit variable is not defined as

```
  //
  if(!userForEdit){
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Modal
      size="lg"
      show={show}
      onHide={onHide}
      aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
    >

      <UserEditDialogHeader id={id} />
      {/* <Suspense fallback={<LayoutSplashScreen/>}> */}
      <UserEditForm
        saveUser={saveUser}
        actionsLoading={actionsLoading}
        user={userForEdit || usersUIProps.initUser}
        onHide={onHide}
      />
      {/* </Suspense> */}
    </Modal>
  );
```

The proper way to handle the problem is to use [Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) to fetch-data-while-rendering but for now, the above case works

Comment: Suspese by teh way an experimental feature https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html